# Testing the multivariable chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, partial-derivative

Let $x = t$, $y = t^2$, and $z = xy$.  Then $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = 2t$$ and since $t = x$, $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 2x = 2t.$$  Everything is consistent.  But now consider using the chain rule
\begin{align}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial\left[z(x,y)/x\right]}{\partial x}\\ &= \frac{\partial\left(z/x\right)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial\left(z/x\right)}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \\
&= -\frac{z}{x^2}\cdot1+\frac{1}{x}\cdot y \\
&= -\frac{xy}{x^2}+\frac{y}{x} \\
&= 0
\end{align}
Certainly, then, something has gone very wrong.  What is my conceptual error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $y$ does not depend explicitly of $x$. You have

$x=x(t)=t$, $y=y(t,x)=t^2$, and $z=z(x,y)=xy$.  Then

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=2t
$$
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}y(t,x)=\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} =\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}
$$
Finally
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial\left[z(x,y)/x\right]}{\partial x}=\frac{y}{x}-z\frac{1}{x^2}=0
$$

Comment: Thanks Pocho.  But is it not fair to say that $y = y(t,x) = t^2 = x^2$?

Comment: In that case,$\frac{d}{dt}y=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=2x =2t$, and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=0 $. (I mean, if $y(t,x)=x^2$.)

Comment: You can notice the subtlety?

Comment: I think I still miss it.  You have both $\frac{d}{dt}y = 2t$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = 0$.  I was not aware this was possible.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}$ is the total derivative, meanwhile $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is the partial derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Actually $y$ being dependent on $t,$ depends on $x.$ But in the second passage (by using the chain rule) variable $y$ is assumed as independent on $x,$ so the result is predictable.